# Exceptions:catch(Exception ex) question

Tags: c#, exception

I understand that when catch is followed by object argument derived from base exception class, it will handle just this exception. But I do not understand why I need to declare a variable of that type, the "ex" or whatever. I know it will be "filled" with the exception object..but just do not get it well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't *have* to specify a variable. For example, you can write:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (IOException)
{
    // Do something
}
```

However, you *usually* want to log the exception or take *some* action which depends on it in some way. (Logging is by far the most common use of an exception variable in my experience - or using it as the "inner exception" for a new exception.) Declaring a variable in the catch statement is how you do that.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thank you. Also I can use type as an argument or type with variable which cause that this variable will be set to instance of that type? I would only need to know how it is terminologically right >]

Comment: @Loj: It's not clear what you mean. It's not an "argument" because you're not calling a method. It's just part of the syntax of a catch block. Have a look at the spec for more details.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: but the MSDN spec says:"The catch clause can be used without arguments, in which case it catches any type of exception, and referred to as the general catch clause. It can also take an object argument derived from System.Exception, in which case it handles a specific exception. "..I am confused now

Comment: @Loj: That's just MSDN being loose with its terminology. It's right that you can just have `catch { ... }` though.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Oh well. So it is not correct to say catch block gets object of exception?

Comment: @Loj: I was more objecting to the use of the term "argument".

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to declare any variable. You can have it like this:

```
try
{
   //something here...
}
catch (ThreadAbortException)
{
   //handle only ThreadAbortException..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
}
catch(SQLException){
//do something not using exception info
}
catch(OtherException ex){
//do something else using exception info
}
catch(Exception ex){
//do something else
Logger.Log(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't declare a variable to contain the caught exception, how are you going to analyze the exception object that was thrown?

If you don't care though, you're not forced to declare it. But generally it's a good idea to in case you want to do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it to find more information about that exception

```
("Exception Message: {0}", ex.Message) or 

about inner exception, ex.InnerException;
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable will contain information about the exception itself, most importantly the message text.

If you just want to catch the exception and clean up and terminate, you may not need it, but generally you will want to display to the user or a log file the actual error message, thats contained in the variable that is populated for you.